# Trying to animate such that the other rectangle below it moves upward?

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, uwp

[image: Screenshot]

```
<StackPanel x:Name="rootStackPanel" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlAcrylicWindowBrush}" Padding="0,48">

    <Rectangle x:Name="sampleRectangle" Width="200" Height="300" Fill="DeepPink" DoubleTapped="Rectangle_DoubleTapped" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform TranslateY="-100"/>
        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
    </Rectangle>
    <Rectangle x:Name="otherRectangle" Width="200" Height="200" Fill="Cyan"/>

</StackPanel>
```

I want to achieve a dynamic look, where, when the pink rectangle is moved upward, the blue rectangle takes up the left over space. Such that it is always touching the pink rectangle.

I have tried manipulating offsets and scale properties provided by visual layer but the actual height is not affected by any of the property, as a result the other rectangle just stays in the original position. Now I am trying to achieve that effect using storyboards animation. But as you can see, the translation property (and the scale property as well) doesn't effect the actual container of the control somehow but rather makes the content in it move to whatever translation.

So, what properties do I need to manipulate to achieve the effect where the other rectangle inside the stackpanel moves dynamically with the changes to the first rectangle?

I know adjusting width or height property would result in what I am trying to achieve but for more complex scenarios where there might be a textbox rather than simple rectangle that is being animated, there is sort of a weird animation of the placeholder text(shrinking of text), which is something I don't want!

Comment: Have you see [`Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Animations.Behaviors`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/animations/scale)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, what properties do I need to manipulate to achieve the effect where the other rectangle inside the stackpanel moves dynamically with the changes to the first rectangle?

You could use  [`Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Animations.Behaviors`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/animations/scale) to realize this feature directly. Before animate your rectangle, you need to get the absolute position of the each rectangle like the follow.

```
var scgt = sampleRectangle.TransformToVisual(Window.Current.Content);
Point screenCoords = scgt.TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0));

var ddv = otherRectangle.TransformToVisual(Window.Current.Content);
Point Res = ddv.TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0));
```

If you want pink rectangle to  move upward, you could `Offset` offsetY value

```
sampleRectangle.Offset(offsetX: 0, offsetY: -(float)screenCoords.Y - (float)sampleRectangle.Height, duration: 2500).Start();
```

And then animate `otherRectangle` like the follow

```
 otherRectangle.Offset(offsetX: -(float)Res.X, offsetY: -(float)Res.Y).Scale(scaleX: 2, scaleY: 2).Start();
```

You need keep `scaleX` equal with `scaleY`  when you scale `TextBox`.Otherwise, the `TextBox` will be deformed.

Comment: Yeah, I did used offset animation to achieve this, and it worked fine for this situation but for more complex situation where instead of a rectangle there is a listview that takes up all the space in a column. When offset animations are applied to it, the listview offsets by the amount and leaves space, thus no longer taking up the entire space provided.